# How to translate “practice a language”

Tags: phrase-requests

What’s the best way to translate a phrase like this:

> Come to our meetup to practice Esperanto!

I often hear people say something along the lines of *praktiki Esperanton*. However, according to [PIV](http://vortaro.net/#praktiki), *praktiki* seems to be more like in the sense of practising medicine. Ie, you put an activity into practice. I guess that technically makes sense in this context but it seems to miss the sense of doing it in order to improve the skill.

On the other hand, the word *ekzerci* seems closer to the meaning I’m looking for:

> **ekzerc/i** (tr) Lertigi per ripetata praktikado

However, the definition in [PIV](http://vortaro.net/#ekzerci) comes with the following remark:

> **Rim**. Neĝuste estas uzi kiel objekton de ekzerci la temon de la ekzercado: oni ne *«ekzercas sian piecon»*, sed *«ekzercas sin al pieco»*

So it seems like saying *ekzerci Esperanton* would mean that I am making Esperanto itself do some work to improve itself.

What is the right formulation to say this?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `ekzerciĝi`

> Ĉu ni kunvenas por ekzerciĝi en esperanta parolado?

or

> ni povas en la daŭro de la tuta jaro multe
>   pli ekzerciĝi, ol en la kelkaj tagoj de la kongreso

both from *Paroladoj de Zamenhof*

`praktiki` is ok too. It's been used for
 language since the beginning:

> sed post kelka praktiko oni tiel facile 
>   alkutimiĝas al la uzado de “vi”

*Lingvaj Respondoj, Zamenhof*

And you can also use `uzi`.

> La stilo Esperanta [...] ellaboriĝis en la daŭro de longa praktika uzado de la lingvo.

*Lingvaj Respondoj, Zamenhof*

In your sample sentence, you can even use `paroli`:

Venu al nia kunveno paroli Esperanton!

Answer (score 1):

**praktiki**

The [Reta-Vortaro](http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/) defines two meanings.

1. Apliki la principojn de arto aŭ scienco: *praktiki kiel kuracistoZ ; praktiki iun artonZ , medicinon, la sportojn, Esperanton; kelkaj jam praktikas tiun regulan sendadon; instruita praktikuloZ.*
2. Efektivigi, realigi: *praktiki la konsilojn de iu; honesta homo praktikas siajn opiniojn; praktiki sian religion, la virtojn, la toleron.*

The first definition mentions Esperanto, but the second definition would match too: use in reality, exercise, apply.

Reta-Vortaro mentions **ekzerci** as synonym (to a degree).

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do by "to practice Esperanto", is to improve your speech and understanding, therefore

> Come to our meetup to practice Esperanto! → Venu al nia rekontiĝo por [plibonigi](http://vortaro.net/#plibonigi) vian Esperanton!

Answer (score 0):

Bonvenon al nia kunveno/aranĝo por

praktiki Esperanton/en Esperanto/la lingvon

trejni Esperanton/lingvouzon de Esperanto/la lingvon/la lingvouzon.

Se la alvoko estos skribita en Esperanto, do uzi varianton "la lingvo" estos evidente.

Comment: Pro tio ke mi menciis la proponon “praktiki Esperanton” jam en la demando, estus bone se vi povus aldoni ian klarigon pri kial vi kredas ke ĝi ja estas la taŭga vorto. Mi pensas ke “trejni Esperanton” havas la saman problemon kiun mi menciis pri “ekzerci Esperanton”. (Oni trejnas homon / beston por io, oni ne trejnas la aferon rekte).